# Creating a directive for a external library in angular 2

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular, dropzone.js

I am just starting out with angular 2, and I have finished doing the basic quick start. Now I am just playing around with it and I have hit a bit of a block. I am trying to use dropzone.js.

I read somewhere else that you could use external libraries by just adding the script, and doing this in your component:

```
//index.html
<script src="node_modules/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>

//app.component.ts
declare var Dropzone: any;
...
constructor(){
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
  //I added a div with same ID as here to my template.
}
```

This didn't work for me. I also tried to use [this](https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670) angular 1 directive for dropzone.js as a reference for creating one for angular 2, but I am a bit lost, as I never worked with angular 1 before.

Comment: Did it give any error message? Are you positive the dropzone.js file loaded? What does `console.log(myDropzone);` right after `myDropzone`'s declaration prints?

Answer (score 3):

After having added the dropzone.js file in your `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/dropzone.js"></script>
```

You could link it to the root element of a component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dropzone',
  template: `
    <div>Drop down area</div>
  `
})
export class DropZoneComponent {
  constructor(eltRef:ElementRef) {
    new Dropzone(eltRef.nativeElement, { url: "/file/post"});
  }
}
```

Here is a plunkr describing this: https://plnkr.co/edit/gV9fuWqALB7g7v7ZxWD4?p=preview.

Comment: I think you need to rely on the injected `ElementRef` to get the DOM element to apply DropZone on... See the `ElementRef` class and its `nativeElement` property

Comment: I didn't see your error message, but on my side this was that ;-)

Comment: Oh sorry ;-) I missed this!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I have tried your suggestion. It seems that the dropzone is being created successfully, however it does not have any functionality (I can't click on it, or drag anything on it for upload). In the angular 1 directive, they added event handlers, do you have any tips for how I could do this here?

Comment: Could you give me some hints about the way you do with angular1 and I'll update my answer to adapt this to angular2? ;-)

Comment: @ThierryTemplier in angular 1, there is [this](https://gist.github.com/compact/8118670) directive for using it in angular 1. Also there is [this](http://www.cantangosolutions.com/blog/Easy-File-Upload-Using-DropzoneJS-AngularJs-And-Spring) from the official Dropzone.js website, although they mention that they take inspiration from their implementation from the first link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is working example:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dropzone',
  template: `
    <div id="myId" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: gray;">Drop down area</div>
    `
})
export class DropzoneComponent {
  private _dropzone: Dropzone;

  constructor() {
    System.import('./dropzone.js').then((dz) => this.initDropzone(dz));
  }

  initDropzone(d: any) {
    this._dropzone = new d('div#myId', { url: '/file/post'});
  }
}
```

[plnkr.co](https://plnkr.co/edit/EAYYjw8VsqsXt21zLrks?p=preview)

1. Install dropzone package locally (for example with npm: `npm install dropzone --save`)
2. Install typings for dropzone (`typings install dropzone --save --ambient`). It will allow you to work with strongly-typed variable.
3. Take a look on promise after dropzone loading - you have to pass variable with function assigned to initializing method (`initDropzone(d: any)`).
4. It is not needed to link dropzone script in index.html. Dropzone is loaded only when the certain component (DropzoneComponent) is loaded.

If you will have any questions you're welcome.

Comment: typings install dropzone --save --ambient didn't work for me, I get 
Unable to find "dropzone" ("npm") in the registry.